# Roaming hardrives on a HPE Proliant DL380 Gen 9 24FF exact copy?

Tags: hp-proliant, diskmanagement, hpe, roaming

HPE Proliant DL380 Gen 9 24FF is faulting due to a flashin read light. The ILM files below indicate that the network port is faulty (attached to the system port). The trouble shooting guides recommend switching the system board.

If we have a second Proliant with the exact same stats can we do a full disk set swap? Will this mean that the system will perform as if it is the original server?
The following link seems to indicate that it should work
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0112214

Will there be issues with Domain (SSL certificates?) and will we have to take it out of the domain and join the domain again?

```
Critical,98,PCI Bus,1,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,1,PCI Bus Error 
(Slot 0, Bus 0, Device 1, Function 0)
Critical,99,Unrecoverable System Error,5,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,4/5/2018 1:04 
PM,1,Unrecoverable System Error (NMI) has occurred.  System Firmware will 
log additional details in a separate IML entry if possible
Critical,100,PCI Bus,2,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,1,Uncorrectable PCI 
Express Error (Embedded device, Bus 0, Device 1, Function 0, Error status 
0x00100000)
Critical,101,Operating System,6,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,4/5/2018 1:04 PM,1,User 
Remotely Initiated NMI Switch
Critical,102,Unrecoverable System Error,3,4/5/2018 1:06 PM,4/5/2018 1:06 
PM,1,An Unrecoverable System Error (NMI) has occurred (System error code 
0x00000000, 0xF000E2C3)
Critical,103,Unrecoverable System Error,3,4/5/2018 1:08 PM,Invalid: 0/0/0 
12:00 AM,1,An Unrecoverable System Error (NMI) has occurred (System error 
code 0x00000000, 0xF000E2C3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move disks between ProLiant systems with similar Smart Array RAID controllers if you keep the disks in the same positions.

The RAID configuration lives on the disks, not the controller.

And no, your SSL certificates and Active Directory won't be affected.